# The logic of Disabling Root Login

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sudo, root, su

Ubuntu 14.04 VPS user here.

My VPS was hacked twice. And the third version is up. Fingers crossed.

The mistake I made in the first two was that I had root + password login enabled. I've learned since that there are brute-force bots out there that keep trying passwords until they get through. So I'm going the private SSH key route this time, no password.

**What I learned** in the process: By default Ubuntu Linux doesn't limit password attempts in any way. You can keep trying different passwords forever. ***~Shiver~***.

I have several questions about the logic of disabling root login:

1. Would it still be possible for the non-root user to use "su" to become root? If yes, then how many password attempts are allowed (i.e., is this too a situation where by default there's no limit to password attempts?).
2. One would still need "root-like" access to the server once in a while, e.g., to give new users "sudo" privileges, etc. Presumably one would have a non-root user account with "sudo" privileges so that one can have such "root-like" access. Why is that not as big of a security threat as having root login enabled?
3. Do experienced Linux server admins typically set up a non-root user such that one would need a private SSH key ***AND*** a password? This seems to me to be the safest option.

Update: I realize that the **root** username is an issue here. But given infinite free attempts, bruteforcing any username + password combination is just a matter of time.

Comment: `root` account has predictable username. Why don't you disable `root` completely and use another user account with `sudo` instead?

Comment: @gronostaj Thanks. Upvoted. I agree that the root username is an issue here. But given infinite free attempts, bruteforcing any username + password combination is just a matter of time.

Comment: @gronostaj I want to add (for future refence) that I didn't want to use another non-root username because that caused issues with using a GUI SFTP client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question: Would it still be possible for the non-root user to use "su" to become root? If yes, then how many password attempts are allowed (i.e., is this too a situation where by default there's no limit to password attempts?).

**Answer: Yes, there is still unlimited attempts to connect using 'sudo' and 'su' by default but you could limit it with pam.d.  The reason this issue is mitigated is because of the delays it takes to issue su and sudo commands programatically.  They are designed to SLOW the attack down so that 'forever' is a VERY long time and bots cannot really do dictionary attacks that are worthwhile at a rate of 1 per X seconds where as with ssh, someone can try passwords at a ridiculously fast rate.**

QUESTION: One would still need "root-like" access to the server once in a while, e.g., to give new users "sudo" privileges, etc. Presumably one would have a non-root user account with "sudo" privileges so that one can have such "root-like" access. Why is that not as big of a security threat as having root login enabled?

**ANSWER: sudo allows users to execute SPECIFIC commands as another user.  You can lock down sudo so that users can only do certain activities.  With full root access, the user is not limited nor tracked. With sudo all activities are also tracked unless of course you gave them sudo to bash (effectively logging in as root via sudo).**

QUESTION: Do experienced Linux server admins typically set up a non-root user such that one would need a private SSH key AND a password? This seems to me to be the safest option.

**ANSWER: Typically root is never allowed to logon directly.  There are no ssh key equivalence set up for root.  Everything is controlled via sudo so that you can track who logged in and did what when.  Typically big companies can only logon as root via the physical console terminal or a virtual console tty.**

Although you didn't ask this, you can somewhat rate limit ssh like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 --rttl --name SSH -j LOG --log-prefix "SSH_brute_force "
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 --rttl --name SSH -j DROP
```